# Renaming Photos in Sequential Alphabetical order

Tags: lightroom, lightroom-4, file-management

Before I start writing an AppleScript to do this I was wondering if anyone knew of any way to rename photos in Sequential Alphabetical Order. Let me give you an example. For one of the papers I do some freelance shooting for I need to attach a job ID that has my initials, job number and then a letter that uniquely IDs the photo. So for my third Job I would need to submit photos named RQ003A, RQ003B, RQ003C etc. Generally the number of photos will never exceed the length of the alphabet (Although if it did I would assume it would either have to go to AA, AB etc. or ZA, ZB etc.). Does anyone have any ideas. I've tagged this with 'Lightroom' as I've just started a trial of Lightroom and quite like it so far, but I am open to other renaming applications. I should also point out I use a Mac.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Lightroom's automatic remaming functionality only supports numerical sequences, see [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/lightroom/using/WSC1A00C68-B970-478b-B83F-45EF52C1C368.html) Adobe help page for a complete list. [ACDSee](http://www.acdsee.com/) seems to support alphabetical sequences based on [this help page](http://acdsee.helpmax.net/en/manage-mode/batch-functions/renaming-multiple-files/) but I haven't used it myself.

Comment: So it does, quite a good batch renaming section, but the rest of it I am not so sold on though. I'll give it the trial see if it impresses me, else it won't be enough to pull me away from Lightroom. Cheers though, good find.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename selected photos in Lightroom when you are in Library mode. Just go to left upper corner popup menu and there is an option "rename photos". There is an option for sequence renaming but I'm not sure at the moment (away from home now) is there alphabetical sequence option. But LR have bunch of options for renaming, like starting point of sequence, adding own names in front of sequence, etc.

Comment: It does not have Sequential Alphabetical Sequencing I'm afraid, thats what prompted me to ask on here. Cheers though.